# How to prevent the duplicating classes error in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I am using [Tesseract](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two) and [Scanbot Android Document Scanner SDK](https://scanbot.io/developer/android-document-scanner-sdk/). Both contain the same class for OCR reading. Since I am using Tesseract I no need to go for the Scanbot PII package which is offering PI packages + OCR. But unfortunately, their PI also contains the Tesseract modules. I need to exclude those classes from scanbot and I tried similar question's answers but it doesn't help.

Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0'
implementation 'io.scanbot:sdk-package-ui:$scanbotSdkVersion'
implementation ("io.scanbot:sdk-package-1:$scanbotSdkVersion"){
    exclude group: "com.googlecode.leptonica.android"
}
```

It gives the following error:

```
Duplicate class com.googlecode.leptonica.android.AdaptiveMap found in 
modules classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar 
(io.scanbot:sdk-core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.leptonica.android.Binarize found in modules 
classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar (io.scanbot:sdk- 
core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.leptonica.android.Box found in modules 
classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar (io.scanbot:sdk- 
core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.leptonica.android.Boxa found in modules 
classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar (io.scanbot:sdk- 
core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.leptonica.android.Clip found in modules 
classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar (io.scanbot:sdk- 
core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.leptonica.android.Constants found in modules 
classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar (io.scanbot:sdk- 
core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.leptonica.android.Convert found in modules 
classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar (io.scanbot:sdk- 
core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.leptonica.android.Edge found in modules 
classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar (io.scanbot:sdk- 
core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.leptonica.android.Enhance found in modules 
classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar (io.scanbot:sdk- 
core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.leptonica.android.GrayQuant found in modules 
classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar (io.scanbot:sdk- 
core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.leptonica.android.JpegIO found in modules 
classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar (io.scanbot:sdk- 
core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.leptonica.android.MorphApp found in modules 
classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar (io.scanbot:sdk- 
core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.leptonica.android.Pix found in modules 
classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar (io.scanbot:sdk- 
core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.leptonica.android.Pixa found in modules 
classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar (io.scanbot:sdk- 
core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.leptonica.android.Pixa$1 found in modules 
classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar (io.scanbot:sdk- 
core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.leptonica.android.Pixa$PixIterator found in 
modules classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar 
(io.scanbot:sdk-core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.leptonica.android.ReadFile found in modules 
classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar (io.scanbot:sdk- 
core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.leptonica.android.Rotate found in modules 
classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar (io.scanbot:sdk- 
core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.leptonica.android.Scale found in modules 
classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar (io.scanbot:sdk- 
core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.leptonica.android.Scale$1 found in modules 
classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar (io.scanbot:sdk- 
core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.leptonica.android.Scale$ScaleType found in 
modules classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar 
(io.scanbot:sdk-core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.leptonica.android.Skew found in modules 
classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar (io.scanbot:sdk- 
core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.leptonica.android.WriteFile found in modules 
classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar (io.scanbot:sdk- 
core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.tesseract.android.PageIterator found in 
modules classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar 
(io.scanbot:sdk-core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.tesseract.android.ResultIterator found in 
modules classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar 
(io.scanbot:sdk-core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI found in modules 
classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar (io.scanbot:sdk- 
core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class 
com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI$PageIteratorLevel found in 
modules classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar 
(io.scanbot:sdk-core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI$PageSegMode 
found 
in modules classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar 
(io.scanbot:sdk-core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI$ProgressNotifier 
found in modules classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar 
(io.scanbot:sdk-core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI$ProgressValues 
found in modules classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar 
(io.scanbot:sdk-core:1.54.0)
Duplicate class com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessPdfRenderer found in 
modules classes.jar (com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.0) and classes.jar 
(io.scanbot:sdk-core:1.54.0)
```

Comment: You have `implementation 'io.scanbot:sdk-package-ui:$scanbotSdkVersion'` twice

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher, double-check it ))